# Calculate fields in a view

Tags: php, join, group-by, mariadb, window-functions

I have the following table "numbers" in my MariaDB database:

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 41 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 73 |
| 5 | 38 |
| 6 | 41 |
| 7 | 12 |
| 8 | 14 |

Now I would like to create a view that lets me see:

- column 1: All possible numbers (distinct)
- column 2: the amount of occurrences of that number
- column 3: the amount of IDs between the last ID and the ID from that number.

That would result in this view:

| number | occurrences | IDdifferences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 0 |
| 25 | 1 | 7 |
| 38 | 1 | 3 |
| 41 | 2 | 2 |
| 73 | 1 | 4 |

So I started with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM numbers
```

and then a left join on the same table to count , but that makes the query verrrry slow (and it didn't work the way I wanted). Do you have any idea how to resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's your MySql server version?

Comment: @Stu 10.4.22-MariaDB-log-cll-lve

Comment: *"column 3: the amount of IDs between the last ID and the ID from that number."* I don't understand. What is "lastID"? Based on what ordering?

Comment: Can ID have gaps?

Comment: @Stu no, no gaps possible.

Comment: @JNevill I mean the amount of records between the last record (max(ID)) and the ID of the last occurrence of the number in column 1.

Comment: I edited MySQL to MariaDB. We need to stop thinking of these products as compatible.

Comment: @Stu unfortunately I just discovered that ID gaps ARE possible :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can group by number and use `COUNT()` aggregate function to get the column `occurrences` and `MAX()` window function to get the column `IDdifferences`:

```
SELECT number,
       COUNT(*) occurrences,
       MAX(MAX(id)) OVER () - MAX(id) IDdifferences
FROM numbers
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number;
```

If there are gaps between the ids:

```
SELECT number,
       COUNT(*) occurrences,
       MAX(MAX(rn)) OVER () - MAX(rn) IDdifferences
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM numbers) t
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=01818a09d1a0b91048e8cd7b7292a48d).

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much! I can go further with this (after hours of trying ;-))

Comment: I just realized there are ID gaps possible. Is there a solution to filter that some way?

Comment: @Erik this depends on what you mean by difference in this case.

Comment: the amount of records instead of the amount of IDs.

Comment: @Erik check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f408a8660510791b57acd00275133809

Comment: You are my hero today. This works perfect!! Thank you very much again!

Comment: my table "numbers" has also a column "date". To calculate the column "IDdifferences" in the view, I only would like to use the amount of records of the last date. I tried with t.max(date), but that did not work. Any idea?

Comment: The other columns shouldn't be affected.